# How I can use IBM's swidgets (com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets) on my SWT application?

Tags: java, maven, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am interested to know how I can use com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets widgets on my application? (for example [this widget](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ledoc/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.javadoc/com/ibm/rcp/swt/swidgets/SButton.html))

I couldn't find them on default Apache Maven repositories but I guess they are not close-source and they are available for own use (also IBM recently [donated](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/lotus/symphony/buzz.nsf/web_DisPlayPlugin?open&unid=955E9C0EC712EC47852578CD0063A209&category=announcements) source of Lotus Symphony (that use these widgets) to Apache Foundation). I think it will be sufficient to show me where is related `.jar`s for swidgets.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swidgets are parts of [IBM Expeditor toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/expeditor-toolkit/). Here is a [simple example of that](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ledoc/v6r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rcp.tools.doc.appdev/tuiswidgets.html).